# Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to the Django rest framework. I want to find users in the database that have the shortest distance to the given coordinates. This is my code:

```
User.objects.extra(
        select={
            'distance': "POW(69.1 * (latitude - %s), 2) + POW(69.1 * (%s - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)"
        },
        select_params=[latitude, longitude],
        where=[
            "is_superuser = false",
            "not id = %s",
            "latitude is not null",
            "longitude is not null",
            "distance < 25"
        ],

        params=[current_user_id]
    )
    .values_list('id', 'distance')
```

and exception:

"Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause"

Comment: Sounds like the `User` model does not have a `distance` field.

Comment: User model does not have a distance field. this field create in the select clause.

Comment: not sure why you use raw sql rather than django ORM

Comment: How do I do with ORM this? "distance" field dynamically calculate from lat and long

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searches then I found a solution. ( @Alvi15 thanks for the comment )

```
querySet = User.objects.annotate(
    distance=Pow(69.1 * (F('latitude') - event_latitude), 2) +
    Pow(69.1 * (event_longitude - F('longitude')) * Cos(F('latitude') / 57.3), 2)
)
querySet = querySet.filter(distance__isnull=False) \
    .filter(distance__lt=25) \
    .filter(~Q(id=current_user_id)) \
    .filter(is_superuser=False) \
    .values_list('id', 'distance')
```